# filtering large data sets to exclude an identical element across all columns

Tags: r

I am a relatively new R user, and most of the complex coding (and packages) looks like Greek to me. It has been a long time since I used a programming language (Java/Perl) and I have only used R for very simple manipulations in the past (basic loading data from file, subsetting, ANOVA/T-Test). However, I am working on a project where I had no control over the data layout and the data file is very lengthy.

In my data, I have 172 rows which feature the Participant to a survey and 158 columns, each which represents the question number. The answers for each are 1-5. The raw data includes the number "99" to indicate that a question was not answered. I need to exclude any questions where a Participant did not answer without excluding the entire participant.

```
Part  Q001  Q002  Q003  Q004
1      2      4    99    2
2      3      99   1     3
3      4      4    2     5
4      99     1    3     2
5      1      3    4     2
```

In the past I have used the subset feature to filter my data
data.filter <- subset(data, Q001 != 99)
Which works fine when I am working with sets where all my answers are contained in one column. Then this would just delete the whole row where the answer was not available.

However, with the answers in this set spread across 158 columns, if I subset out 99 in column 1 (Q001), I also filter out that entire Participant.

I'd like to know if there is a way to filter/subset the data such that my large data set would end up having 'blanks' when the "99" occured so that these 99's would not inflate or otherwise interfere with the statistics I run of the rest of the numbers. I need to be able to calculate means per question and run ANOVAs and T-Tests on various questions.

```
Resp  Q001  Q002  Q003  Q004
1      2      4          2
2      3           1     3
3      4      4    2     5
4             1    3     2
5      1      3    4     2
```

Is this possible to do in R? I've tried to filter it before submitting to R, but it won't read the data file in when I have blanks, and I'd like to be able to use the whole data set without creating a subset for each question (which I will do if I have to... it's just time consuming if there is a better code or package to use)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the "99" by "NA" and the calculate the colMeans omitting NAs:

```
df <- replicate(20, sample(c(1,2,3,99), 4))
colMeans(df) # nono

dfc <- df
dfc[dfc == 99] <- NA
colMeans(dfc, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: This worked great in the example you provided, but when I tried to apply it to my large data set I am receiving an error that states 'x' must be numeric.

I imported the data with header = TRUE and when I look at my data set the headers are the only things with numbers. All columns contain 1-5 and <NA> now. Is it possible that the program isn't interpreting my numbers as integers? I might try reimporting all the data to see if somewhere in my attempts to not calculate the 99s I broke something else!

Comment: I must have messed something up when I imported, I just reloaded and it worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also indicate which values are NA's when you read your data base. For your particular case:

```
mydata <- read.table('dat_base', na.strings = "99")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
will na.strings also allow me to read blanks/missing spots as na? I've tried to read data in before which had blanks in some areas, am I able to say 
mydata <- read.table('dat.base', na.strings = "99", na.strings = "")
or is there some other way to make R automatically read missing spots in a table as NA?
I usually have to open the data in excel first and replace all missing cells with NA/0/whatever works for the data i'm working with, but the data set I have is so large that I can't even open it in a single excel file, so being able to do it all in R would be amazing!

Comment: from ?read.table: "Blank fields are also considered to be missing values in logical, integer, numeric and complex fields". You don´t need excel if you know R!

Comment: Yes, you can do it as follows: read.table ('dat.base', na.strings = c("","99"))